# Improve PostgreSQL SELECT performance in a parent table (inheritance)

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I have a PostgreSQL 9.2 database where each account has a schema, like below:

```
My_Database
 |-> Schemas
    |-> AccountA
    |-> AccountB
    |-> AccountC
    |-> AccountD
    |-> AccountE
           .
           .
           .
    |-> AccountZ
    |-> MasterAccount
```

All schemas have a table called `imovel` which has a column called `id`, the structure is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MasterAccount.imovel_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE MasterAccount.imovel (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('MasterAccount.imovel_id_seq') NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(80) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE AccountA.imovel (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('MasterAccount.imovel_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY
)
INHERITS (MasterAccount.imovel);

.
.
.

CREATE TABLE AccountZ.imovel (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('MasterAccount.imovel_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY
)
INHERITS (MasterAccount.imovel);
```

Today i have 127 accounts and when i run a `SELECT` in a child table, the response is fast. But when i run the same `SELECT` in the father table, it is slow. I saw the `EXPLAIN` and seems that PostgreSQL uses each child's INDEX, instead of use only the father INDEX.

Is it possible to improve this behavior? Below are the EXPLAIN.

I need to use `SELECT` in the Master table for global searches.

**SELECT in the child table**

[image]

**SELECT in the father table**

[image]

Comment: Database query-performance questions are better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Andreas, Oh, thanks! I'll post there!

Comment: I would have expected a query like that to process in parallel. Since it doesn't, according to the access plan, you might want to look into the parallel settings of your database, to make sure parallel processing is not disabled.

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks, i will check! Do you know what is the directive config, please?

Comment: I could do a web search to find out, but then again, so could you, and you'd have gotten an answer faster than asking here.

Comment: @Andreas: Postgres 9.2 does not support parallel queries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Ahh, right, that was added in 9.6.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting from `MasterAccount.imovel` will select from all child tables, so it is not surprising that it takes much longer. The query won't use the index on `MasterAccount.imovel` because that table itself contains no data, so it makes no sense to use the index. I guess your misconception is that an index on the parent table will index all child tables, but that is not the case.

You also cannot benefit from parallel query because you are using a very old, outdated PostgreSQL version. Upgrading to v12 would help, but only concerning the query response time: parallel processing does not reduce the resources used.